# Contain top-bar contents to grid with Foundation 6

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Is it somehow possible to contain the contents of a `top-bar` to the grid with Foundation 6?

In Foundation 5 this was possible to get with the `contain-to-grid` class but unfortunately this isn't available anymore.

I've already tried to use a `grid-container` with `grid-x` and two 6 cells in it instead of `top-bar-left` and `top-bar-right`, but somehow the grid-container shrinks to its minimum size when placed inside a `top-bar`.